# Jena Fuseki missed inference?

Tags: jena, owl, fuseki

I'm using Jena Fuseki 3.13.1 (with `OWLFBRuleReasoner`), and I have asserted (uploaded) the following triples:

```
@prefix rdfs: <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#> .
@prefix owl: <http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#> .
@prefix f: <http://vleo.net/family#> .

f:Bob f:hasWife f:Alice .
f:Bob f:hasWife f:Alice2 .
f:Alice2 f:hasHusband f:Bob2 .

f:hasWife a owl:FunctionalProperty .
f:hasWife a owl:InverseFunctionalProperty .
f:hasHusband owl:inverseOf f:hasWife .
```

Now, If I query and `ASK { f:Alice owl:sameAs f:Alice2 }`, I get true.

However, If I `ASK { f:Bob owl:sameAs f:Bob2 }`, I get false! Loading the same triples on another reasoner (owl-rl), I get the triple `f:Bob owl:sameAs f:Bob2` inferred.

What is happening here?

Comment: not sure, maybe a bug - the rules are [here](https://github.com/apache/jena/blob/master/jena-core/src/main/resources/etc/owl-fb.rules): rule `inverseOf2` and `ifp1` should lead to the inferred triple. You should ask on the Jena mailing list, Dave Reynolds (the main dev of the inference layer) is usually answering pretty fast there

Comment: @AKSW thanks for the hint! I'll report this to the Jena mailing list

Answer (score 0):

I have worked with jena reasoner following this doc:
https://jena.apache.org/documentation/inference/
I have many years of experience with jena, and had never used OWLFBRuleReasoner, and it does not appear in the indicated doc, which is curious for me.

Not all reasoners work with the same construct, and that is the reason why I check the doc, that means perhaps OWLFBRuleReasoner does not use the same owl construct as the another reasoner you used (owl-rl).

Another thing is that, as I understand your KB is inconsistent, because you are declaring:
f:hasWife a owl:FunctionalProperty

But, you are assigning 2 values to it, which must make your KB inconsistent.

Luis Ramos

Comment: that is not correct, the KB is not inconsistent

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

A follow-up: as suggested by UninformedUser, I've asked this one on the Jena mailing list and got an answer from Dave.

Jena's implementation trades some reasoning completeness for performance, the solution in this case is to add explicitly the forward version of `inverseOf` to the owl-fb rules file:

```
[inverseOf2b: (?P owl:inverseOf ?Q), (?X ?P ?Y) -> (?Y ?Q ?X) ]
```

The details are in this [thread](https://mail-archives.apache.org/mod_mbox/jena-users/202001.mbox/%3c1011895859.6.1578581385798.JavaMail.zimbra@vleo.net%3e).